# How to access lines from a referenced BufReader in Rust

Tags: rust, filestream, ownership

I'm just trying to figure out how ownership works in Rust, I just have an example file helper as :

```
pub struct FileHelper {
    pub reader:Option<BufReader<File>>
}

impl FileHelper {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        FileHelper{ reader: None }
    }

    pub fn open_read(&mut self, file:&str) {
        let file_stream:File = File::open(file).expect("FAIL");
        self.reader = Some(BufReader::new(file_stream));
    }

    pub fn get_reader(&self) -> Option<&BufReader<File>> {
        match &self.reader {
            Some(reader) => { return Some(reader); }
            None => { return None; }
        }
    }
}
```

All it does it separate the creation of a `BufReader` and the retrieval of the same `BufReader`. I'm using it as :

```
let mut file_helper:FileHelper = FileHelper::new();

file_helper.open_read("/tmp/someFile.txt");

match file_helper.get_reader() {
    Some(reader) => {
        for read_line in reader.lines() { println!("{:?}", read_line.unwrap()); }
    },
    None => {}
}
```

It seems to be able to get the reference to the `BufReader` but I'm unable to interact with the `reader.lines()` because it gives the error :

```
move occurs because `*reader` has type `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

So I'm guessing the `reader.lines()` is trying to take ownership? I don't really understand how the ownership and referencing is working here but was wondering if there's a way to still use the `reader.lines()` on a referenced `BufReader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BufRead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) is implemented for [impl<B: BufRead + ?Sized> BufRead for &mut B](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#impl-BufRead-for-%26mut+B). But you are returning a **shared reference** to underling reader. Method [BufRead::lines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) **consumes** `self`. Since you provided `&BufReader` compiler tries to dereference it and **take** `BufRead` which is impossible since it is behind a shared reference and is not `Copy`.

Solution is very simple. Just return **exclusive/mutable reference** to the buf reader.

```rust
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::fs::File;

pub struct FileHelper {
    pub reader: Option<BufReader<File>>
}

impl FileHelper {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        FileHelper {reader: None }
    }

    pub fn open_read(&mut self, file: &str) {
        let file_stream: File = File::open(file).expect("FAIL");
        self.reader = Some(BufReader::new(file_stream));
    }

    pub fn get_reader(&mut self) -> Option<&mut BufReader<File>> {
        self.reader.as_mut()
    }
}

fn main() {
   let mut file_helper: FileHelper = FileHelper::new();

    file_helper.open_read("/tmp/someFile.txt");

    if let Some(reader) = file_helper.get_reader() {
        for read_line in reader.lines() {
            println!("{:?}", read_line.unwrap());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, returning `Option<&mut BufReader<File>>` instead of `Option<&BufReader<File>>` fixed it, thanks so much!

Comment: @TheLovelySausage You're welcome. You might also be interested in reading [this section](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#generic-readerwriter-functions-take-r-read-and-w-write-by-value-c-rw-value) of Rust API Guidelines.

Comment: Yes very much so, Rust is still very mysterious to me